# Python's multiprocessing scope behaving differently on two machines: why can't I access variables defined in '__main__'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope, multiprocessing

I am trying to understand why the scope on python's multiprocessing class is different between two computers. On the first computer, variables defined in `'__main__'` are not accessible in the function that I am calling with `pool.map(func)`. However, on another computer, this program works.

Here is a minimal working example. In the function `mapping_func(idx)`, I do not directly pass the array arr as an argument.

- On my mac, this program produces an error on the line `a = arr[idx]` saying `arr` is not defined.
- On my ubuntu machine, the program has no error and runs.

````
import multiprocessing
import os
import numpy as np
import time

def mapping_func(idx):
    a = arr[idx]
    time.sleep(1)
    print(a)
    return a

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    arr = np.linspace(0, 20, 11)

    with multiprocessing.Pool(os.cpu_count()) as pool:
        pooled = pool.map(mapping_func, np.arange(len(arr)))```
````

Comment: The difference between your two machines is that `multiprocessing` uses "spawn" mode on one, and "fork" mode on the other.  To have values accessible to all processes, regardless of mode, they need to be assigned outside of the `__name__ == '__main__'` block.

Comment: Even when forked the variables are copies and aren’t shared between processes.  Shared memory is required for a change to be visible between processes

Comment: Thank you very much! On https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html it says that spawn is default on windows and mac, while fork is default on linux. When I set multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn') on my linux machine, then I had the same behavior as my mac.